# Patch antenna design

Tags: rf, radiation

Can anyone assist me regarding the design of a circular polarized rectangular patch antenna that is driven at adjacent sides through a power divider?

I already calculated the parameters of the width and length of the patch and the substrate size. However, I am having difficulties calculating the positioning of the microstrip transmission line in order to get a circularly polarized antenna. I am running at a frequency of 915MHz, using FR-4 substrate and a height of 1.6mm.

Comment: If you have additional information related to your original question, use the "edit" button to add the information there. Do not create a duplicate question.

Comment: @DaveTweed I have posted that previous question before no one helped, hence I thought a new question was necessary. Hoping someone may help this time...

Comment: When you edit your question, it will bump it up to the front page, which will give it more attention. There's nothing with bumping up your question. Duplications make things messy on our website, however, so that's why we advise you not to do that.

Comment: @KingDuken duly noted, my original question as been answered now. Do you suggest I delete this duplicate or leave it?

Comment: I don't think it matters since a moderator already flagged it as duplicate.